# Vscode Snippets how to change the format of CURRENT_DAY_NAME

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

[The official document of VScode snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) specifies that the variable CURRENT_DAY_NAME is used to output the current name of day, like 'Monday', but I want to ouput the day in format in Chinese, Like '星期一'.

I was wondering whether this can be achieved with regular expression replacement, but I did not figure out how to operate it.

Comment: you can have a look at this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#datetime

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in the extension's document, it said: `The transform you can apply to fields in snippets is not supported in the variables in the task and launch json files.

With the command extension.commandvariable.transform you can find-replace with Regular Expression a selection of variables combined with static text.`， it seems this extension can't used in snippet, is I understand right?

Comment: if your usage of snippets is to get an initial content in a file you might have a look at [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates), inside the template you can specify the date the same way and snippets for particular parts

Comment: @rioV8 I think the first plugin you recommend worked for me. I can use that plug-in to customize a shortcut key to insert the date in chinese format, and then select the date and use it as an input for snippets to achieve the function I want. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I did not find how to directly define variables in snippets, but use this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#datetime) to customize a shortcut key to insert Chinese date format. Then select this date and use it as the input in snippets to achieve the desired function.

Thank your very much for @rioV8 's recommend.